# Passing message from View Controller to a class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

By using delegates, I'm trying to pass data from a view controller to a TableView class that will display the correct number of cells. First, I needed to pass the array to that class (using a String here instead for debugging)

Inside my ViewController:

```
protocol GroupBillVCDelegate{
  func passFriendArray(string: String)
}

...
class GroupBillViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    var delegate:GroupBillVCDelegate? // for delegate passing message

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (tableView == self.FriendTableView){
            let friendListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendListCell") as! CategoryRow

            // transfer friends array to CategoryRow
            self.delegate?.passFriendArray(string: "Hello There")

            return friendListCell
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the TableViewCell class:

```
class CategoryRow: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, GroupBillVCDelegate {

    var s:String = String()

    func passFriendArray(string: String) {
        s = string
        print(string)
    }

...

    // used for horizontal scrolling
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        passFriendArray(string: s)   // message supposed to appear here
        print ("TEST")
        return 10
    }

...

}
```

I have trouble setting up the delegate. When I run, the console does not display the message. Why is it not being passed?

Comment: where are you assigning `delegate`?

Comment: sorry, it was under  class GroupBillViewController

Comment: You have a declaration to hold the `delegate`, but that just means it's `nil` until you assign a value to it.

Comment: There is no need to use a delegation pattern in this case, and even if there was, you aren't setting the delegate property anywhere. You can simply assign to the `s` property of your new cell object and use a `didSet` if you want to take some action after that assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a delegate as an intercom on your desk that can be connected to your assistant's office.

This line:

```
var delegate:GroupBillVCDelegate? // for delegate passing message
```

Defines the intercom, but doesn't connect it to anything. If you press the button on the intercom, it doesn't connect to anything.

The code `self.delegate?.passFriendArray(string: "Hello There")`

uses "optional chaining" to send a message to the delegate if there is one, and drop the message if there is no delegate.

The thing you're missing is assigning something to the delegate:

```
self.delegate = someObjectThatConformsToGroupBillVCDelegateProtocol
```

A delegate is a one-to-one relationship.

All that being said, it doesn't really make sense to make a table view cell the delegate of a view controller. The table view has more than one cell. Which cell should be the view controller's delegate? Why that cell and not another one?

Comment: would the self.delegate = someObjectThatConformsToGroupBillVCDelegateProtocol be inside the Sender or Receiver class? And should I instantiate an object of the receiver class for the right side of that statement?

Comment: It should be inside the object that has the delegate. In your `GroupBillViewController` object, in this case. (I'm not sure how to use the terms `Sender` and `Receiver` in this context.) As for how to create your delegate object, I have no idea. It depends on what it is and who owns it.